# Using LESS in the Padrino Ruby framework

Tags: css, ruby, less, assets, padrino

I am pretty new to the Padrino framework (and ruby in general) and have been looking into using padrino's built-in support for the LESS CSS preprocessor for a new application I am developing. I decided to fully commit to LESS for this project as I am using Twitter's Bootstrap framework as a base for my UI.

So my question is, how do I go about using padrino's LESS support in my workflow, both during development (where I'd want the .less source files to be compiled on the fly and reloaded on every page refresh), and in production (where padrino should be serving a single css file compiled from all the .less source files, which would all be correctly ordered and @imported in a "master" application.less file).

I can see that when I generate a padrino project choosing less as the css preprocessor that I get a "stylesheets" directory in both the /app directory, where I assume the .less files should go, as well as the /public/stylesheets directory where I assume a compiled .css file would sit. What I am unsure of is how do I "define" my LESS assests to padrino and how far does its built-in support go, and how much management will I still have to do manually?

And FYI, my development environment is Mac OSX Lion, and the pow rack server. For production I am still deciding on a host, put am leaning towards heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LESS with Padrino with a component. See http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/generators

```
padrino g project your_project -c less
```

EDIT: If you want to add LESS to existing application: http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/adding-new-components

Answer (score 0):

[CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) should fill your "on the fly" needs. I haven't used it myself as I only use Snow Leopard, [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless), has filled my needs (until an SL version of CodeKit appears).